# Can't play Vine/Instagram video's in Chrome webbrowser

Tags: google-chrome, video, video-streaming, instagram, vine

I asked this question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45867/cant-play-vine-instagram-videos-in-chrome but it isn't a very populair site form SE so I thought let's ask it here too.

I installed chrome because I have a new laptop. But now when I wan't to play Vine/Instagram video's it doesn't display them. I only get the sound. These video's are .mp4 I guess.

What could be the problem? I've noticed that more people have this problem, but haven't found a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my answer from a user on Web-Applications SE site.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46108/35759

I had the same problem and was able to use **Steve Wingfelder's** [workaround](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/297tWaAYyGo/uCgzS-pv1isJ) (numbers added for ease of reading)

> Temporary Fix:
>
> 1. Enter “Chrome://flags” in the address bar.
> 2. Find an entry that says
>      “Disable hardware-accelerated video decode.”
> 3. Click “Enable”.
> 4. Your
>      videos should now play just fine

Your problem also could be related to plugins. Some found **Gokul's** [suggestion](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/DrLRUK6g0wU/wdqPENzAqBUJ) to work:

> - Type **chrome://plugins** click on **+details** find the **PepperFlash** entry and click Disable.Use only Adobe plugin.
> - Check your extension causes the trouble.Disable them one by one and check.

Comment: Not available on my platform but thank you for the info! I can't believe this didn't just show a warning / explanation on the site. :(

Answer (score 0):

I installed about a hundred libraries and plugins to get this working and to my amazement I finally got it working! This is how I did it:

1. Right click on the Instagram video and select "inspect element"
2. Copy the video link to clipboard and execute "wget [paste link here]" in a shell.
3. Upload the video to Youtube and watch it from there.

Remember to set the privacy setting to "Private" to avoid copyright issues when uploading.

Would have saved a lot of my time if I had figured this out right from the start...

Comment: Why should you upload an instagram/vine video of let's say 5 seconds? I already solved the problem in chrome. This is a very bad alternative.

Comment: If the answer you accepted was an universal solution, then by all means. But this is not about what works for you. Disabling hardware acceleration solves nothing when HW accel is not even available, as in my case. Neither does disabling PepperFlash when it is has not even been installed. So please next time think in advance before labeling something that just works as a "very bad alternative." Obviously it is a better alternative than something that does not work.

Comment: I already asked it here, because it became offtopic here http://superuser.com/questions/628716/cant-play-vine-instagram-videos-in-chrome#46108